# Spring Integration File Outbound Channel Adapter and file last modified date

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to make a File Outbound Channel Adapter to write a file having the last modified date attribute set to a custom value instead of system current time.

according to the documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-timestamps) I'm supposed to set the `preserve-timestamp` attribute to `true` on the outbound and set the header `file_setModified` to the desired timestamp in the messages.

Anyway I made several attempts without success.

This is a code snippet to show what I'm doing right now:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="msg.channel"
    expression="'Hello'">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:header-enricher
    input-channel="msg.channel"
    output-channel="msgEnriched.channel">

    <int:header
        name="file_setModified"
        expression="new Long(1473897600)"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="msgEnriched.channel"
    preserve-timestamp="true"
    directory="/tmp/foo"/>
```

what's wrong with that?

(using Spring Integration 4.3.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timestamp` value is overridden if your `payload` is a `File`:

```
Object timestamp = requestMessage.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.SET_MODIFIED);
...
if (payload instanceof File) {
    resultFile = handleFileMessage((File) payload, tempFile, resultFile);
    timestamp = ((File) payload).lastModified();
}
...
if (this.preserveTimestamp) {
    if (timestamp instanceof Number) {
        resultFile.setLastModified(((Number) timestamp).longValue());
    }
}
```

To avoid that override and really get a gain from the file_setModified, you should convert the `File` from the `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` to its `InputStream`:

```
<transformer expression="new java.io.FileInputStream(payload)"/>
```

before `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

The documentation warns about that though:

> For File payloads, this will transfer the timestamp from the inbound file to the outbound (regardless of whether a copy was required)

**UPDATE**

I have just tested your use case and my `/tmp/out` directory looks like:

[image]

As you see all my files have the proper custom last modified.

What am I missing?

Maybe that `1473897600` (1970 year) is wrong for your operation system?

**UPDATE**

OK! The problem that `preserve-timestamp` isn't configured into the target component during parsing that XML: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4324

The workaround for your use-case is like:

```
<int:outbound-channel-adapter id="msgEnriched.channel">
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler">
        <constructor-arg value="/tmp/foo"/>
        <property name="preserveTimestamp" value="true"/>
        <property name="expectReply" value="false"/>
    </bean>
</int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

instead of that `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>` definition.

Comment: Thanks Artem for clarification. However, what about the case when the payload is not a File, like in the example I posted (and as it happens in my real use-case)? It doesn't seems to work anyway.

Comment: The example you posted is exactly about `File` payload `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` produces files. You can debug the `FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage()` and check what's going on with your payload.

Comment: there's something I don't get. Isn't the `expression="'Hello'"` in the inbound-channel-adapter producing `String`s?

Comment: Doh... I see now your code. Let me test it locally! Anyway: how about to debug the mention code?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I guess it's something related to my OS then (Linux, tested both on a Fedora 26 and a CentOS 7). I also tried using a more recent timestamp and using different filesystems with different mount options but with any effect. I'll just make more tests and let you know!

Comment: Artem, I tested that same configuration on a Windows machine and it's still not working. Would you please share your `xml` config?

Comment: I used Java DSL and did it already on SI 5.0. OK, I'll come back to you lately with some Spring Boot app for SI 4.3.11

Comment: Ha! I really see the behavior you explain. And indeed last modified is the current system time... Stay tuned - I'll come back to you with the solution!

Comment: See one more UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: thanks! the workaround works like a charm! Are there any chance to see the `preserve-timestamp` feature on SFTP outbound too?